# menu item won't show in action bar

Tags: java, android

I can't get an action button to appear in the action bar. I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding how this is supposed to be done. What am I doing wrong?

I'm going through the tutorial at developer.android.com and I've just added an item to the action bar. In the tutorial, the `showAsAction` for a Search button is set to `ifRoom` and it should show the button in the action bar, but it's only showing it in the overflow menu.

I thought there might not be enough room, so I've tried reducing the title of the app to a single letter. I've tried removing the title of the button.  I've tried changing the `showAsAction` to every value except `never`.

---

**Update 20150830_151538-0500**: Changed `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` per recommendation in answers. The result is that the Search button doesn't show at all. Not even in the overflow. I also included the full MyActivity.java rather than just the snippet I included in the original question.

---

---

**Update 20150831_222922-0500**: There were two problems. The first was that I used `android:showAsAction` rather than `app:showAsAction`. This was pointed out right away in the first two answers. The second problem was that I was using an icon that was the wrong size. I was using one of the `_48dp.png` icons and that caused the item not to show at all because it was the wrong size for the action bar. This was pointed out in comments to the answer by @ci_.

---

---

**Note**: The original version of MyActivity.java, which was generated by Android Studio, inflated a menu_my.xml file for the menu. This menu file only included the Settings action using `app:showAsAction="never"`. Following the tutorial, I replaced the content of the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` class. Unless I'm misunderstanding something this original menu_my.xml file isn't used at all, but since I started properly using `app:` instead of `android:` for the items that Settings item is the only one that's showing. I doubt it's related, but I wanted to mention it just in case.

---

MyActivity.java:

```java
package com.ghodmode.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.ghodmode.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the Send button
     */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

main_activity_actions.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />
</menu>
```

Comment: If you're using ActionBarActivity you have to use the appcompat namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake when using the `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` from the support library, which I'm assuming you're using here.

In this case a special appcompat namespace has to be used for `showAsAction`:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

If that still doesn't work for you, change the `showAsAction` back to `never`. If it now appears in the overflow menu, there is something wrong with your icon.

Comment: I apparently am using AppCompatActivity, but changing `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` didn't change anything. `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` was already there. I thought I wasn't using AppCompatActivity because the tutorial I'm following suggested that I would have to take extra steps in order to implement it. I guess that the code generated by Android Studio when creating a new project automatically uses AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I just realized that after changing `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` the Search item doesn't appear in the overflow at all. So, even though your recommendation makes perfect sense, it's actually a step backward for me.

Comment: Sounds unusual. Change ifRoom back to never. If it shows in the overflow then, there's something wrong with your icon. If not, you're not looking at the right menu file. Clean your project and rebuild. Maybe there are build errors?

Comment: That fixed it! Setting it to "never" makes it show in the overflow. Setting it back to "ifRoom" and removing the `android:icon` line makes it appear where I wanted it. Now I have to figure out what's wrong with my icons, which were just downloaded from [Google's Material Icons collection](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html), but that's another topic.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: The problem I had with the icon is related to the size I selected. When I downloaded the Material Icons pack, I didn't know what the different versions of the images were... 18dp, 24dp, 36dp, 48dp. I just picked 48dp for no particular reason. It only works with 24dp, as in ic_search_white_24dp.png. I think this is related to the size of the action bar which I haven't learned how to change yet. I probably wouldn't want to change it from the default anyway. @ci_ please add your last comment to your answer so it'll be found more easily if someone else encounters this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding to your menu xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and then use:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: Your recommendation and the one made by @ci_ are essentially the same. The `xmlns:app` part was already there because Android Studio included it, but changing `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` (either `ifRoom` or `always`) results in the Search button not appearing at all. Not even in the overflow.